# Format to be changed in strings

Tags: c#, datetime

My string contains the value: `08/20/2012-10.32.19`

I want the output in string datatype itself as `08/20/2012 10:32:19` [format is `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`].

Please help!!

Comment: I tried many ways using `String.Format` but didn't get the right approach

Comment: Where are you getting this string from?

Comment: I'm using a MVVM Model in a WPF application therefore my webservice is giving the response for a datetime interms of string datatype itself. I need to pass the formatted string `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` to a Model object which inturns bind to a Textbox control in XAML using `binding` tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may convert the string to `DateTime` and then use `.ToString()` with the required format.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("08/20/2012-10.32.19", "M/d/yyyy-HH.mm.ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string test = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Test will have

```
08/20/2012 10:32:19
```

**EDIT:**  based on the comment

You may specify multiple date formats and then parse accordingly.

```
string[] formats = new string[] { "M/d/yyyy-HH.mm.ss", "yyyy-M-d-HH.mm.ss" };
string dtTest1 = DateTime.ParseExact("08/20/2012-10.32.19",
                                     formats, 
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                     DateTimeStyles.None)
                                     .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Or in a single line

```
string dtTest2 = DateTime.ParseExact("08/20/2012-10.32.19",
                                     new string[] { "M/d/yyyy-HH.mm.ss", "yyyy-M-d-HH.mm.ss" }, 
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                     DateTimeStyles.None)
                                     .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

This will satisfy your both case of dates:

```
08/20/2012-10.32.19
2012-08-20-10.32.19
```

Comment: You are calling `ToString()` on string, you need to parse it first to `DateTime` and then call the `ToString()`, the above code works

Comment: I'm using a MVVM Model in a WPF application therefore my webservice is giving the response for a datetime interms of string datatype itself. **Can i have a single line of code** to pass the formatted string `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` to a Model object which inturns bind to a Textbox control in XAML using `binding` tag.

Comment: @sukumar, MVVM was not in the question and I m  not too sure about it, but the above can be done in one line like `string Test = DateTime.ParseExact("08/20/2012-10.32.19", "M/d/yyyy-HH.mm.ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: Thank you Habib. I used a single line of the same code. But seems looks like no alternative the approach of first conversion to DateTime and then Format to our custom way.

Comment: @sukumar, may be you can use string operations like `Replace` and others to get your required string, but since your string is a date, `DateTime` is a better approach IMO

Comment: there is a new change. As i told you earlier that these date information interms `string` data type is coming from a webservice. somewhere in code for one property,the webservice response for a date is coming in string as `2012-08-20-10.32.19`. Then your code   `string Test = DateTime.ParseExact("08/20/2012-10.32.19", "M/d/yyyy-HH.mm.ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");` gets **FAILED**. Please help me out as not stick to use only one format type itself.

Comment: For more info please see the question posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172371/custom-string-data-type-datetimes-to-a-formatted-datetime-string-data-type

Comment: @sukumar, you have to specify all the possible format in the format array, otherwise it won't work and your new question might get marked as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

You may use very simple becouse your string only require fiormating

```
String a="08/20/2012-10.32.19".Replace('-', ' ').Replace('.', ':');
```

I hope this work for you

Comment: vow!! It's amazing and Great work!! Thank you. I used this code line itself in my code.

Comment: hey your code gets fails for a string `2012-08-20-10.32.19`. Somewhere for one property of datetime string i'm getting this value. this is throwing exception as Invalid Date. Please help!

Comment: @sukumar, That is the exact reason, that you should use `DateTime`, using it as string will give you problems when you are expecting multiple string formats for dates

Comment: Hi, you are change the string format so that it is not recognised so you need to parse the string and tell about your format so that you can use only a single format , String a=DateTime.ParseExact("2012-08-20-10.32.19", "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")

Comment: @user1622434, you can pass an array of string formats, check my edited answer and try it in visual studio

Comment: @Habib yes I try it,It works, great work so in the array all format is required and if array not have format alwayes same exception is occured

Answer (score 0):

We have various inbuilt format like `ToLongDateTime`, `ToShortdateTime` in .Net

```
string formatDate = txtdte.ToShortDateTime();
```

This returns string so no need of any other conversion. If you are specific about your format, ToString takes parameters like `ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")`

Comment: If `txtdte` itself `string` data type then i don't think  `ToShortDateTime` will be shown in intellisense. If you are well known about using this format with my requirement please provide a example.